# how to get object from one class to another in android?

Tags: android

Need an idea on how we can get an object from one class to another in android? I need to get an object of one class to another to set title in collapsing toolbar.I have a ListView in one Fragment and after clicking the list item another activity is opened where i want to get ListView name and set title on collapsing toolbar.

Comment: You can simply pass the name as string.

Comment: use serializable or Parcelable. Parcelable is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

you can use intent and putExtra method

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity2.this, activity1.class);
intent.putExtra("message", message);
startActivity(intent);
```

Put the name you want to pass instead of message.

Comment: where you are handling the click for your list.

Comment: will putExtra() gives each list item name to next activity toolbar??

Comment: It will pass on whatever you want it to. Say you want to send the string "xyz" to the activity you are starting, just replace "message" with string "xyz".

Comment: quite confusing :D :D

Comment: You should probably go for basics first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass `object` from one class to another using `Bundle` then `Parsable` or `Serializable` are two ways to achieve that. But it's **not** a good coding practice to pass object through `Bundle`. You should instead **pass parameters of that object** in `Bundle` and create that object in receiver class.

Answer (score 0):

You can putExtras() in an Intent and then in the activity use getExtras() method to get whatever you put in.

Or if they are just simple classes and not activities then simply make the elements static and asses them by making an object of that class in the second class.

See [This](https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwitsJX0vobKAhUWjo4KHVHeCS0QFggZMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F5265913%2Fhow-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data&usg=AFQjCNE5FufDvoqK_v7PPo5e8aHGT06lxg&sig2=JNnMOM7XfobVw7_RXPIhDQ&bvm=bv.110151844,d.c2E) question to know how to putExtras().